# Creating a NSUTF8 NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am calling a string value from an object I have created and passing it into a NSString, however I am not making sure its NSUTF8 for international characters.

This is how I call it.

```
masterString = [dict valueForKey:@"MASTER"];
```

How am I able to make sure this is a NSString of UTF8 type?

Comment: NSString is characters of (conceptually) UNICODE type.  When you convert it to `char*` you can specify the conversion -- UTF8 or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding used by a `NSString` instance to store the unicode characters is an implementation detail. You only provide encoding when creating a new string instance or when you want to retrieve the stored characters as bytes in a given encoding.

I guess that you are looking for one of the methods `-[NSString UTF8String]`, `-[NSString dataUsingEncoding:]` or `-[NSString getCString:maxLength:encoding:]`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. the trouble I have been having is with this CString stuff.. I am trying to store these values into coredata which only use 'string' for their string types.. so im abit lost as to how to handle this.

Comment: Core Data can handle NSString just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[NSString class reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)
NSString is implemented as array of UNICODE characters. Only when you convert NSString into array of plain chars (C string) or bytes (NSData) you care about encoding.